# How can I convert a UTF-8 encoded file with BOM to a UTF-8 encoded file without BOM in Azure Data Factory V1/V2?

Tags: azure, utf-8, azure-data-factory

I currently have a V2 Data Factory which copies UTF-8 encoded files with BOM to a storage location and I would like to remove the BOM as part of the standard copy activity.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is actually very simple to do. In the output dataset, if we do not specify an encoding Data Factory will then use UTF-8 by default without adding the BOM.
The following datasets illustrate this principal:

Here is my input dataset:

`{
    "name": "InputBlobs",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": "|",
                "rowDelimiter": "",
                "nullValue": "\\N",
                "encodingName": "UTF-16",
                "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
                "skipLineCount": 0,
                "firstRowAsHeader": false
            },
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": "folder_path"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}`

Here is my output dataset :

`{
    "name": "OutputBlobs",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "columnDelimiter": "|",
                "rowDelimiter": "",
                "nullValue": "\\N",
                "treatEmptyAsNull": true,
                "skipLineCount": 0,
                "firstRowAsHeader": false
            },
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": "another_folder_path"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there is no such middleware processing mechanism for you to remove `bom header` in `Azure Data Factory Copy activity`.

However,  I provide you with a workaround that you could use [Blob Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to execute business logical code when your file moved into blob storage.

***remove bom sample code:***

```
public static string RemoveBom(String desc, Encoding encode)
{
    string bomString = encode.GetString(encode.GetPreamble());
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bomString) && desc.StartsWith(bomString))
    {
        desc = desc.Remove(0, bomString.Length);
    }
    return desc;
}
```

Hope it helps you.